# SQL query to fetch all Auctions for whom a particular user has not submitted a Bid

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a project where I want to fetch from my postgres database all the auctions where a particular user has not submitted any bid for the auctions. I am trying to write the query for this.
The schema is as follows -

**Auction Table**

| auction_id (PK) | auction_data |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | a1_data |
| A2 | a2_data |
| A3 | a3_data |

**Bids Table**

| bid_id (PK) | auction_id (FK) | user_id | bid_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | A1 | U1 | P1 |
| B2 | A2 | U1 | P2 |
| B3 | A1 | U2 | P3 |
| B4 | A2 | U2 | P4 |
| B5 | A3 | U2 | P5 |

**The constraint is that for each auction any user can submit only a single bid.**
So ideally the query should return Auction id as A3 if the input to it is find auctions where user U1 has not submitted a bid.

How to accomplish this? I know we can do multiple joins to find the result but I am looking for something a little straight forward. Not sure if there is any in-built function to make the query a little less complex. I don't have much experience so struggling to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT A.AUCTION_ID
   FROM AUCTION_TABLE A
EXCEPT
SELECT B.AUCTION_ID
  FROM BIDS_TABLE B WHERE B.USER_ID='U1'
```

Could you please try this

Comment: This works thanks!! But if I want auction_data for those auctions as well, can I do it in single query or do I join this auctionList with Auction table to get the data, as EXCEPT needs same tuples in both SELECT queries.

Comment: You can try if different approach SELECT A.AUCTION_ID,A.AUCTION_DATA FROM AUCTION_TABLE A LEFT JOIN (SELECT B.AUCTION_ID
  FROM BIDS_TABLE B WHERE B.USER_ID='U1')X ON A.AUCTION_ID=X.AUCTION_ID WHERE X.AUCTION_ID IS NULL